# Flask method PUT not returning something

Tags: python, flask

Hello gus so I have this code:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True



@app.route('/set', methods=['POST'])
def set():
   auth = request.args.get('auth')
   username = request.args.get('username')
   password = request.args.get('password')
   return auth


app.run()
```

What I want to do is that I want to be able to work with those variables but I wanted to see if I can get them at first, I have runned the script and entered the link:

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/set?auth=hello&username=adi&password=123

I get the "Method Not Allowed" when I run that and no output as it should return the auth value

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allow `get` method:

```
@app.route('/set', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```